# How to find out more about hashed string?

Tags: authentication, encryption, hash, encoding

I have an agent providing access tokens in this format:

```
ccccccdhitvt kfffrnhudkberdundntihbddlleuhbkn
ccccccdhitvt fcbjeeinrjnnldkvbtndbbbnhdbuffuv
ccccccdhitvt fgdvcvtbjdctflbuhtcjicvllgvdjeuj
ccccccdhitvt kkddicnulbfgcgvkuijkuhjbnduhhfte
ccccccdhitvt ccnijgkglhblkudnkdffvtvhbjutvtbn

ccccccdhitvt tdiiinurdedcicvngfviueveicnhdekt
ccccccdhitvt dnnjdrgilbtgidtcgrdenldgncjdgued
ccccccdhitvt hvbchlcrulbuucretchrbgdijgidvbcv
```

The space is inserted by me to emphasize the cutoff of the fixed part (12 characters) from the variable part (32 characters). The second part might be a timestamp, although tokens seem to be valid for a pretty long period.

To me this does not look like a salted hash or anything like that (at least not in combination, the variable part might be one). It would be interesting to find out if this is a security problem for my customer. How would i go about finding out if these tokens have any easily discernible meaning?

**Edit 1**: There is no syncronization between the generator and the consumer so tokens NEED to have the generation date and time embedded in them to prevent reuse or delay attacks. This means that the process is reversible and the "hashed" information is probably retrievable.

Comment: Get the source code and look into it. Other than that, you can try a few things, but there are really many different ways one can represent timestamps.

Comment: Here's some observation: this is a custom Hex character set (there are only 16 different characters) and the first part is probably a fixed salt. The second part is probably the output of MD5 or HMAC-MD5. There are still too many possibilities to make it a good and answerable question. You would have to find the correct permutation/mapping of hex to bytes and find the correct hashing function (if any)

Comment: Its a shot from the hip. I know that it is a hard question. Maybe i should add a tag like "forensics". Thank you for the effort!

Comment: You can only determine the length of the ciphertext or hash, but that's about it: [How to determine what type of encoding/encryption has been used?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-to-determine-what-type-of-encoding-encryption-has-been-used) Keep in mind that this could also be an AES ciphertext or ciphertexts of any other 128 bit block ciphers.

Comment: It's just an authentication token. I assume that the encoded data is about the same size as the output string. This is why i think that this might be much simpler than assumed. There is no syncronization between the generator and the consumer so tokens NEED to have the generation date and time embedded in them to prevent reuse or delay attacks. This is also why I assume that the hashing is reversible.

Comment: @IgorSkoric If it is reversible is is not a hash.

Comment: @zaph I am aware. Please help me with the correct term. I assume that it might not be a hash.

Comment: It is a string of bytes where each byte is comprised of two characters from a set of 16 [bcdefghijklnrtuv]. It may be a hash in which case it is not reversible.

Comment: I don't see a more fitting name in that definition. Thanks for the effort.